# Indentation in org num mode

Tags: org-mode, indentation

When working with both org indent mode and org num mode turned on, I observe that text lines are aligned with the outline numbering, like so

[image]

which looks cluttered to me. Instead I'd prefer an alignment with the headline text as in the following example:

[image]

I am wondering whether there is a quick and clean solution to this, e.g. by simply setting some variables. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don´t have a ready solution. It is possible, but not quick and clean. Some pointers: It would involve redefining `org-indent--compute-prefixes` to take the added characters into account. Then re-calculation of indents needs to be done when org-num is activated/deactivated.

Comment: It is perhaps even worse, because the width of the numbers can vary (`1` vs, `1.1` vs `1.10`) so the prefix will vary from headline to headline. Not worth the bother IMO.